# Why does a usb c adapter not offer voltage under load

Tags: usb-c

I have bought a usb c pd board (12V) (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000460866867.html) and such a GnA usb c charger (https://www.amazon.de/-/en/UGREEN-Charger-Supports-Compatible-MacBook-black/dp/B091BRJSRN). Additionally I have a Li-Ion Battery Pack 3S with BMS.

I thought that it should be possible that I just wire them up as you would normally do. But after I did so, nothing happened. After some time I figured out that if you connect the battery after you connected the usb c cable, everything works fine.

So I mesured and found out that my usb c charger takes approximately 1-2 seconds to reach 12V.

> But why is that so?

Do you have an idea how to wait until it reaches 12v?
I have tried:

1. Putting a self-made coil in series (didn't change anything)
2. Use a Relai which triggers at 11V (worked but after it was triggered once the battery started keeping the relai open)
3. Use a Relai plus a Mosfet (as Diode) (worked as expected but dropped the voltage by 0.6V so that I wasn't able to charge my battery to 100%)

Comment: Connect them as you usually do, what does that mean? Into what load? Are you connecting the Mains USB adapter via the USB PD directly to a lithium battery with a BMS?

Comment: 1. Yes exactly "usb c charger" -> "usb c pd" -> "bms" -> "battery" 2. the bms/battery is the load

Comment: Unfortunately, most readers here are tired of answering questions about aliexpress purchases that don't work as expected. Try to buy from a more reputable vendor in the future.

Comment: "*...  takes approximately 1-2 to reach 12v.*" 1 - 2 what? Seconds? "*a self-made spule*" What is a 'spule'? 'V' for volt, not 'v'. "**No datasheet? No sale!**"

Comment: It's part of the USB PD standard that the power supplies initially delivers 5V. Then it starts the USB PD communication and offers additional voltages. The power source (the USB PD board in your case) can then select a higher voltage. If it does, the power supply will switch to that voltage. That takes 1 to 2 seconds. Your simple USB PD board has no switch to turn the output on and off. It passes the input voltage through: first 5V, then something intermediate, then 12V. Your BMS is likely confused by this behavior and shuts off.

Comment: @Codo ahh now I understand. But even though the BMS shuts off, I should be able to mesure 12V at the output of the usb c pd. But I don't.

Comment: @Transistor I have updated my question. I don't have a datasheet.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson In my opinion, I think it doesn't matter if you buy the same board from amazon for 30€ or from aliexpress for 2€. It is the same chip and board. Moreover the board does work, I just don't understand why it does what it does.

Comment: "Same chip and board"? Not necessarily. It may **look** the same but you may get counterfeit chips and poor assembly. And I would **not** suggest Amazon or Ebay as reputable vendors for electronic assemblies. No datasheet, no sale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not connect lithium batteries directly to power supply output. Stop immediately what you are doing before either the batteries or power supply is damaged, and please understand that damaged batteries may be dangerous and can explode or burst into fire. You also don't know if they have been damaged already, so it may not be wise to keep using them, it might be a good idea to recycle them properly.

You are missing a critical component in your system, a lithium battery charger, which takes in power from the power supply and uses it to charge the lithium batteries safely.

No, your power supply is not a lithium charger.
No, a BMS is not a lithium charger either.
You need a lithium charger between power supply and the battery pack.

What most likely happens is that when power supply tries to give 12V, too much current flows into batteries and the charger shuts down due to overcurrent situation. Also since batteries output more than 5V, the output may go into overvoltage shutdown mode before the power supply even outputs 5V. This is just plain wrong usage of power supply and battery.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Now I have understood that.